Laravel not processing FormData in a PUT request
I'm facing an issue while trying to send a PUT request with FormData in Laravel using Inertia. I need to update a user, but the PUT request seems to be ignored, and Laravel is not processing the FormData correctly. I was sending the PUT request via Inertia.js, but when I checked the request in Laravel, I found that the request body was empty.
Here’s the flow I'm following:
I’m trying to send FormData from the frontend (via Inertia.js).
The PUT request is not being processed as expected.
I checked the Laravel request body using dd($request->all()), and it came up empty.
Here’s what I tried and how the request came up empty:
Code for debugging in the controller (Laravel):
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // Debugging the request body
    dd($request->all()); // This shows an empty array
    
    // Trying to check php://input
    $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    dd($rawData); // This shows data
}

Frontend (Inertia.js with FormData):
javascript

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('first_name', model.first_name);
formData.append('last_name', model.last_name);
formData.append('email', model.email);
formData.append('is_superuser', model.is_superuser);
formData.append('is_active', model.is_active);
formData.append('password', model.password || ''); // Optional field
formData.append('profile_pic', model.profile_pic);


router.put(route('user.update', { id: userData.id }), formData, {
    preserveScroll: true,
    onError: (errors) => {
        const errorList = Object.entries(errors)
            .map(([, value]) => `${value}`)
            .join('\n');
        alertDialogService.setMessage(errorList).show();
    },
    forceFormData: true, // Ensure FormData is sent
});

Laravel Controller:
php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    dd($request->all()); // Check the incoming request data
    
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|max:30',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:30',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:auth_users,email,' . $id,
        'is_superuser' => 'required|boolean',
        'is_active' => 'required|boolean',
        'password' => ['nullable', 'min:8'],
    ]);

    // Find and update the user data
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->update($validatedData);

    return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('success', 'User updated successfully.');
}

What I observed:
When I checked the Laravel request, I found that the request body was empty ($request->all() returned an empty array).
I tried using file_get_contents("php://input") to read the raw data, it shows the formData.
How can i fix it? is there any extra configurations needed using vue inertia?

Are you sure this line formData.append('profile_pic', model.profile_pic); is working fine?have you checked that?Also check whether you have correctly set Content-Type to multipart/form-data.

i tried sending without the profile pic field as well. and other combinations also. I debugged in the network tab and formdata seems fine. But the laravel side can't seem to find the formdata. i am using inertia route and the create method seems to get the form data not working for put.

The workaround involves changing the request method to POST, while also informing Laravel that this is intended to be a PUT request by adding a _method field to the FormData.
Here's how you can implement this solution:
Frontend (Inertia.js with FormData)
Instead of sending a PUT request directly, modify the FormData and use a POST request:
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('first_name', model.first_name);
formData.append('last_name', model.last_name);
formData.append('email', model.email);
formData.append('is_superuser', model.is_superuser);
formData.append('is_active', model.is_active);
formData.append('password', model.password || ''); // Optional field
formData.append('profile_pic', model.profile_pic);

// Add the _method field to indicate this is a PUT request
formData.append('_method', 'PUT');

router.post(route('user.update', { id: userData.id }), formData, {
    preserveScroll: true,
    onError: (errors) => {
        const errorList = Object.entries(errors)
            .map(([, value]) => `${value}`)
            .join('\n');
        alertDialogService.setMessage(errorList).show();
    },
    forceFormData: true, // Ensure FormData is sent
});

No changes are needed in your Laravel controller code for this solution. Laravel will recognize the _method field and correctly interpret the request as a PUT request.
Explanation

FormData with _method Field: By adding _method: PUT to the FormData,
Laravel can interpret the POST request as a PUT request.
Using router.post: You send the request as a POST rather than a PUT.
This avoids the issue where Laravel fails to parse the request body
when using PUT with multipart/form-data.
Symfony's Limitation: The underlying issue is related to Symfony,
which Laravel uses for handling HTTP requests. Symfony doesn't
natively parse multipart/form-data correctly for PUT/PATCH requests.
This is why using POST with a _method override is a common
workaround.

This solution should resolve the issue of Laravel showing an empty request body and allow you to update the data successfully.
